# What could be the possible cause of this inconsistent time complexity?

Tags: python, windows, math, time-complexity, computer-science-theory

I have created a script that requires a number of calculations to be performed.
I am currently performing valuation of it's time complexity and there appears to be a few inconsistencies when the number of calculations are low.

The calculations are fairly simple and I would expect the time complexity to be linear however, up until the ~20 000 calculations the execution time seems to double, regardless of how many more calculations are performed.
The only difference between each iteration of running the code is the number of calculations i.e the number of loops entered and all that other jazz is the same

After about 20 000 calculations we can see that the relationship conforms to a linear trend. What could be the potential causes for this? I have a limited understanding of computer science, but my limited knowledge brain is thinking it could have something to do with my CPU clock speed being 2.1MHz - but this is probably a coincidence. The data is attached below, including a graph of the overall time complexity. What could be happening at the start when the calculations are low? All help is appreciated! Thank you

| Number of Calculations | Execution Time (s) |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1.0739 |
| 1000 | 1.5066 |
| 5000 | 1.7258 |
| 10000 | 1.8882 |
| 15000 | 2.0061 |
| 20000 | 2.1536 |
| 25000 | 2.4743 |
| 35000 | 3.1681 |
| 50000 | 4.9021 |
| 75000 | 7.7399 |
| 100000 | 8.9756 |
| 500000 | 42.1814 |
| 1000000 | 82.0846 |
| 5000000 | 416.8664 |
| 7500000 | 624.5523 |
| 10000000 | 825.1506 |

[image: Data]
[image: Graph of Data]
[image: Graph2 of Data]

Comment: don't post images. post data as text. You say that the timing is linear, but there's no way for us to take this data, make a plot and verify it. Also without posting your code is difficult to guess.

Comment: You're choosing somewhat random intervals, which makes it hard to visualize the pattern.  If you're trying to figure out the time complexity by staring at the data rather than analyzing the code I'd suggest plotting the data on a graph to make it easier to stare at.

Comment: Please show your code (in as close to [mcve] form as possible, of course)? And probably also start counting operations performed (and inner-most codepath execution if you're doing deeply nested/recursive execution) rather than just time/percentages.

Comment: Hi all! Thank you for your comments. I have added the plain text data, as well as two graphs that help to visualise the data. The overall trend according to the first graph is linear, but there is a bit of 'funky business' happening before ~20 000 calculations. What could be the cause of this? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This might be due to the function’s runtime being a linear function with a very large intercept term. For example, suppose your function’s runtime is T(n) = n + 100000. Then if you start looking at ratios of the form T(2n) / T(n), you’ll see values of the form

> (2n + 100000) / (n + 100000) = 1 + n / (n + 100000).

For small values of n, this will be much, much less than 2, even though the “canonical hallmark” of a linear function is that it roughly doubles as n doubles. However, as n increases, the second term gets closer and closer to 1, and eventually the ratio approaches 2.

As for what might cause this, that could be anything from a slow program startup time due to loading a large binary, or the overhead of an interpreter starting up, or the cost of calculating some huge table, etc. But without seeing the code and workflow it would be hard to say which.